# Call a method in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm Having difficulty understanding what seems to be a simple error.
When I call a method defined on my react component AlarmList called addNewAlarm, that method calls this.showAlarms().  I would think that would not cause a problem but I get an error `undefined is not a function`.  This seems like it should be pretty straightforward as that is how you call a class method in javascript.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...

export default class AlarmList extends React.Component {
  addNewAlarm() {
    this.showAlarms();
  }
  showAlarms() {
    alert('showing alarms');
  }
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Add An Alarm"
        onPress={this.addNewAlarm}
      />
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: is this a `this` binding issue? i.e you either need to use a class property arrow function or add a `constructor()` with `this.addNewAlarm = this.addNewAlarm.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your function declaration to

```
addNewAlarm = () => {
   this.showAlarms();
}
showAlarms = () => {
   alert('showing alarms');
}
```

Or bind it in the constructor like

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.addNewAlarm = this.addNewAlarm.bind(this);
   this.showAlarms = this.showAlarms.bind(this);
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind it

```
<View>
      <Button
        title="Add An Alarm"
        onPress={this.addNewAlarm.bind(this)}
      />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because ***this*** in this context is of method instead of class and there is no such methods defined in your method addNewAlarm(). This is more general problem of lexical ***this***.

You can solve it in three ways(you should adopt the first way, and if you don't like it then you should go for the 2nd one)

1. convert the declaration

   addNewAlarm() {
       this.showAlarms();
     }

to

```
addNewAlarm = () => {
    this.showAlarms();
  }
```

2. Let the declaration be

   addNewAlarm() {
       this.showAlarms();
     }

But write a constructor inside your class

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.addNewAlarm = this.addNewAlarm.bind(this)
}
```

3. (Not recommended) Bind addNewAlarm while calling like this

   onPress={this.addNewAlarm.bind(this)}